# How to see tasks in Calendar both Windows 8 application and web application calendar.live.com

Tags: windows, calendar, windows-live, windows-8-calendar-app

May be I'm missing something obvious but...
I can't see my tasks neither in Windows 8 Calendar application nor in web version (which is synced with Windows 8).
By the way creation of tasks is available only in web version. But after I've created it I can't see it anywhere at UI.

Comment: As for me, I would prefer to see all my tasks together with my calendar appointments without switching views. Is there a way to do that? It seems, no... BTW, Google Calendar can do that - I'd like to see this in Microsoft Online Calendar too.

Answer (score 0):

In the website, you can click on "view" in the upper right corner and select "tasks".

However, I am still looking for a Metro app too.